# Position a rectangle at the rightmost side of the container

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

How can I place the rectangle (referred to as `right1`) at the rightmost side of the screen? I want it to clip but it is overflowing somehow.

[image]

I also tried to give `overflow: hidden` to `overlayContainer` but somehow it keeps overflowing.

```
<div className={styles.overlayContainer}>
  <Diamond styleName={styles.left1} />
  <Diamond styleName={styles.left2} />
  <Diamond styleName={styles.right1} />
</div>
```

The styles for `right1` are:

```
height: 36px
width: 36px
top: 200px
right: -24px
```

The `Diamond` component is simply a `div` with these two styles applied to it

```
.diamond
  position: absolute
  transform: rotate(45deg)
```

**EDIT**
[image]
I want to position the element like this.

Comment: Can you put up a working code snippet reproducing the issue ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak The code is in React. How should I show the snippet? And it also has a lot of components to it. How can I position elements on the right side like this? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two main things.

1. Ensure the `body` element has `max-width: 100vw;`
2. Ensure the `body` element has `overflow-x: hidden;`

You probably still want to scroll on the Y axis (up/down).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/eknowles/pen/xxwOgrW?editors=1100)

```html
<div class="diamond" />
```

```css
html, body {
  max-width: 100vw;
}

body {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.diamond {
  background: gold;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But why `overflow-x: hidden` was working only on `body` and not on the parent container - `overlayContainer`?

Comment: Nice, so the `overlayContainer` probably has a width of `100%` but it's the parent that controls the overflow, but you can override it at the root element which would be the `body`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused due to this css

right: -24px;

```
right:0;
```

if this doesn't fix it kindly post your code.

Comment: Oh I want to position the rectangle like that.

Comment: using right:0; provides the same effect, except without overflowing :)